# Why does my timer bar stop at a certain point?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a series of Javascript, CSS and HTML mini games. In these games, I have a timer that I use on a progress/timer bar. Here, the bar moves until a certain point.
The problem is that in all of the games it works perfectly except for one and the code is the same in all of the games.

This is the code for the progress/timer bar:

```
const leftTime = document.getElementById("leftTime");
const countDown = document.getElementById("countDown");
function initBarCount() {
  let startTimer = setInterval(barCount, 480); //width of bar is 250px
  console.log("start timer: " + startTimer);
  function barCount() {
    if (leftTime.clientWidth < countDown.clientWidth) {
      leftTime.style.width = leftTime.clientWidth + 1 + "px";
      console.log("1: " + leftTime.style.width);
    } else {
      leftTime.style.width = countDown.clientWidth + "px";
      console.log("2: " + leftTime.style.width);
      clearInterval(startTimer);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code for the timer. (2 minutes)

```
function startTimerGame() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (container.style.display == "none") { //open/close container
      container.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      container.style.display = "none";
    }
    guessField.value = ""; //reset input
    createGame(); //start game variables
    resultText.innerHTML = "El resultado final es: " + finalScore;
    playGameButton.disabled = false;
  }, 120000 /*300000*/);
}
```

This is the code for the button you click to start the game.

```
playGameButton.onclick = function() {
  resultText.innerHTML = "";
  finalScore = 0;
  leftTime.style.width = 0 + "px";
  startTimerGame();
  initBarCount();
  if (container.style.display == "none" || playGameButton.disabled == false) {
    container.style.display = "block";
    playGameButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    container.style.display = "none";
    playGameButton.disabled = false;
  }
};
```

I've noticed that something odd happens with the problematic game:
Any suggestions on what is happening? If you could tell me what the problem is, I would appreciate it a lot since I do not have any idea of how to proceed and to be honest, this language is new to me.

Comment: debug: `console.log(leftTime.clientWidth, countDown.clientWidth, leftTime.clientWidth < countDown.clientWidth)`

Comment: I already did something similar. Have a look at this https://imgur.com/a/t1ZJuj6

Comment: but you are not looking at what the other width is to see why.... guessing you need to figure out why the width is only 6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the **clientWidth** property is taking longer to update than the next interval is called. Try setting the interval longer to see if it fixes the issue.

If you want to still use the same short interval, try doing something like this instead:

```
leftTime.style.width = (parseInt(leftTime.style.width,10) + 1) + 'px';
```

Comment: The second part of your solution worked perfectly !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a philosophical change in logic, which would likely fix your issue, but I would use percentages for the width of the progress indicator.

Since you have a container bar and a progress bar, then the progress shouldn't care about how many pixels wide it is, just that it is some percentage through the total timer amount. Something like this will always get the progress width to end at the container width, regardless of container width or timer duration.

```js
const progressEl = document.getElementById('progress');
const totalTime = 5000;
let elapsedTime = 0;
const tickInterval = 1000 / 60;

const interval = setInterval(elapse, tickInterval);

function elapse() {
  progressEl.style.width = (elapsedTime / totalTime * 100) + '%';
  elapsedTime = Math.min(Math.round(elapsedTime + tickInterval), totalTime);
  
  if (elapsedTime === totalTime) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
width: 250px;
border: 2px solid #95a5a6;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.progress {
background: #16a085;
height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your code looks more cleaner and easy to understand than my solution. I will try this.